# SSD OCZ Agility 3 Series 120GB SATA III 6Gb/s interface

Tags: ssd, sata

I have never owned an SSD and am considering getting the above for Christmas, I can see a mixture of reviews good and bad but frankly I haven't got a clue what to get if I don't get a SSD.
And so to my question the OCZ Agility 3 Series has SATA III 6Gb/s interface for £120 and the OCZ Vertex 2 120GB SATA II 3Gb/s is at £125 and as the cheaper one is faster cheaper and has a better rating it seems the best buy.

I'm just a little worried as my Cross-hair III Formula Motherboard only supports 3Gb/s sata, so can I still buy the 6Gb/s version and just get a bottle neck or will it throw up an error? on install.

Sorry for the dummy Question, best to be safe than sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That said:

- SATA 3 works on SATA 2 ports.
- Yes, you are then limited to around 300mb/second, under random load this is a LOT more than any disc will ever get you.
- Vertex is quite similar in speed to Agility. It is more expensive but has more reserves (cells wear out, so heavy duty drives have more reserves than light duty). The agility is the light duty drive.

The Vertex is crap prior to the 2.15 firmware which you can upgrade the drives to yourself. I have 6 of them and they blew the hell out of any Raid and regularly got stuck. After the upgrade they behave. Still not totally ok, but they (OCZ) works on the last bugs.

Comment: I had an OCZ Vertex that had the same issue. Drive was dropping data. I recommend if you do go OCZ to put the latest firmware on it before using it.

Comment: Actually that I did - and it solved things so far ;) But it was a painfull set of onths until then.